# Create multiple gitlab job pipelines from build list

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build a list of images that are all in subfolders, the structure is `imagename/Dockerfile`

Currently's I'm doing this in one job, but I would like to have gitlab create a pipeline for each build.

```
build_images:
  stage: build
  script:
    - for image in $(cat image.list); do docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$image" ./$image; done
    - for image in $(cat image.list); do docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$image"; done
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: what about create a job for each build ?

Comment: sure is there a way to create a job from each line item?